# Powershell to split large csv. Taking Very long. Hoping to shorten process via code review

Tags: powershell, csv, split

The csv is about a gig and has over 1million rows. I'm attempting to split it into 5. The first 4 take about 18 hours - the 5th never happens ( or I havnt been patient enough) my pc will just sit in a sleep mode because it wont unlock.

```
function Split-Csv{

    [CmdletBinding()]

    Param(

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]

        [string]$FilePath,

        [Parameter()]

        [string]$Delimiter=',',

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]

        [string]$TargetFolder,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]

        [string]$Name,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]

        [int]$NumberOfFiles

    )

 

    try{

        if(-not (Test-Path $TargetFolder)){

            New-Item -Path $TargetFolder -ItemType Directory

        }

 

        $csvData=Import-Csv -Path $FilePath -Delimiter $Delimiter

 

        $startRow=0

 

        $numberOfRowsPerFile=[Math]::Ceiling($csvData.count/$NumberOfFiles)

 

        $counter=1

 

        while($startRow -lt $csvData.Count){

            $csvData | Select-Object -Skip $startRow -First $numberOfRowsPerFile | Export-Csv -Path "$TargetFolder\$Name-$counter.csv" -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber

            $startRow+=$numberOfRowsPerFile

            $counter++

        }

    }catch{

        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message

    }

}
Split-Csv -FilePath "C:\temp\2018.csv" -Delimiter ',' -TargetFolder "C:\temp\Split" -Name "Split" -NumberOfFiles 5
```

Comment: This would be not so hard to do and very efficient using .NET APIs if you treat your CSV as plain text instead of objects, but chunking it into __X pieces__ is problematic, it would be easier if you chunk the file into pieces __of X Length__

Comment: Problem with that is the file is too large to open. It crashes my pc

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - it relies on the data not containing line breaks in the literal data - e.g. ```"aaa, bbb`r`nxxx, `"yyy`r`nzzz`""``` so you don't split a record across files, but that's probably a reasonable assumption. in *most* cases..

Comment: See also: [Read CSV sheet in batches using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73774733/1701026)

Answer (score 2):

You can give this function a try, as I stated in comments, this will be much faster and memory friendly if you use the .NET APIs instead of treating the CSV as objects.

This function uses the [`StreamReader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-6.0) and [`StreamWriter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-6.0) classes to read and write line by line.

Usage examples can as well as it's [`Merge-Csv`](https://github.com/santisq/PS-CsvUtil/blob/main/public/Merge-Csv.ps1) counterpart are available through the [**PS Gallery**](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSCsvUtil) as well as in the official [**GitHub Repo**](https://github.com/santisq/PS-CsvUtil/).

```bash
using namespace System.IO
using namespace System.Text
using namespace System.Management.Automation
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Language
using namespace System.Collections
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

# All Credits to jborean93 on the EncodingTransformation Class
# Source: https://gist.github.com/jborean93/50a517a8105338b28256ff0ea27ab2c8#file-get-extendedattribute-ps1

class EncodingTransformation : ArgumentTransformationAttribute {
    [object] Transform([EngineIntrinsics] $EngineIntrinsics, [object] $InputData) {
        $outputData = switch($InputData) {
            { $_ -is [Encoding] } { $_ }

            { $_ -is [string] } {
                switch ($_) {
                    ASCII { [ASCIIEncoding]::new() }
                    BigEndianUnicode { [UnicodeEncoding]::new($true, $true) }
                    BigEndianUTF32 { [UTF32Encoding]::new($true, $true) }
                    ANSI {
                        $raw = Add-Type -Namespace Encoding -Name Native -PassThru -MemberDefinition '
                            [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
                            public static extern Int32 GetACP();
                        '
                        [Encoding]::GetEncoding($raw::GetACP())
                    }
                    OEM { [Console]::OutputEncoding }
                    Unicode { [UnicodeEncoding]::new() }
                    UTF8 { [UTF8Encoding]::new($false) }
                    UTF8BOM { [UTF8Encoding]::new($true) }
                    UTF8NoBOM { [UTF8Encoding]::new($false) }
                    UTF32 { [UTF32Encoding]::new() }
                    default { [Encoding]::GetEncoding($_) }
                }
            }

            { $_ -is [int] } { [Encoding]::GetEncoding($_) }

            default {
                throw [ArgumentTransformationMetadataException]::new(
                    "Could not convert input '$_' to a valid Encoding object."
                )
            }
        }

        return $outputData
    }
}

class EncodingCompleter : IArgumentCompleter {
    [string[]] $EncodingSet = @(
        'ascii'
        'bigendianutf32'
        'unicode'
        'utf8'
        'utf8NoBOM'
        'bigendianunicode'
        'oem'
        'utf7'
        'utf8BOM'
        'utf32'
        'ansi'
    )

    [IEnumerable[CompletionResult]] CompleteArgument (
        [string] $commandName,
        [string] $parameterName,
        [string] $wordToComplete,
        [CommandAst] $commandAst,
        [IDictionary] $fakeBoundParameters
    ) {
        [CompletionResult[]] $arguments = foreach($enc in $this.EncodingSet) {
            if($enc.StartsWith($wordToComplete)) {
                [CompletionResult]::new($enc)
            }
        }
        return $arguments
    }
}

function Split-Csv {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByChunks')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [alias('FullName')]
        [string] $Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $DestinationFolder,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'BySize')]
        [int64] $Size = 1kb,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ByChunks')]
        [int32] $Chunks = 3,

        [Parameter()]
        [EncodingTransformation()]
        [ArgumentCompleter([EncodingCompleter])]
        [Encoding] $Encoding = 'utf8',

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $PassThru
    )

    begin {
        $Destination = $PSCmdlet.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($DestinationFolder)

        class ChunkWriter {
            [FileInfo] $Source
            [string] $Destination
            [string] $Headers
            [string] $Format
            [Encoding] $Encoding

            [StreamWriter] GetNewWriter([int32] $Index) {
                $name     = [string]::Format(
                    '{0} - Part {1}{2}',
                    $this.Source.BaseName,
                    $Index.ToString($this.Format),
                    $this.Source.Extension
                )
                $newChunk = Join-Path $this.Destination -ChildPath $name
                $writer   = [StreamWriter]::new($newChunk, $false, $this.Encoding)
                $writer.AutoFlush = $true
                $writer.WriteLine($this.Headers)
                return $writer
            }
        }
    }
    process {
        try {
            [FileInfo] $Path = $PSCmdlet.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Path)
            $null    = [Directory]::CreateDirectory($Destination)
            $reader  = [StreamReader]::new($Path.FullName, $Encoding, $true)
            $headers = $reader.ReadLine()
            $Index   = 0

            if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByChunks') {
                $chunkSize = ($Path.Length - $headers.Length) / $Chunks + ($headers.Length * $Chunks)
                $format    = 'D{0}' -f $Chunks.ToString().Length
            }
            else {
                $chunkSize = $Size - $headers.Length
                $format    = 'D{0}' -f [math]::Ceiling($Path.Length / $Size).ToString().Length
            }

            $chunkWriter = [ChunkWriter]@{
                Source      = $Path
                Destination = $Destination
                Headers     = $headers
                Format      = $format
                Encoding    = $Encoding
            }

            $writer = $chunkWriter.GetNewWriter($Index++)

            while(-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
                if($writer.BaseStream.Length -ge $chunkSize) {
                    $writer.Dispose()

                    if($PassThru.IsPresent) {
                        $writer.BaseStream.Name -as [FileInfo]
                    }

                    $writer = $chunkWriter.GetNewWriter($Index++)
                }
                $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine())
            }
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
        finally {
            $writer, $reader | ForEach-Object Dispose

            if($PassThru.IsPresent) {
                $writer.BaseStream.Name -as [FileInfo]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code on various sizes of CSVs:

```
$incsv = Import-Csv .\BigCsv.csv

$incr = [int]($incsv.Count / 5)
$last = $incsv.Count - 1

$idx = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -le $last; $i += $incr)
{
    $end = $i + ($incr - 1)
    if ($end -gt $last) { $end = $last }
    $idx += @{ 'Start' = $i ; 'End' = $end }
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++)
{
    $start = $idx[$i].Start
    $end = $idx[$i].End
    $incsv[$start..$end] | Export-Csv -NoType ".\Chunk$($i+1).csv"
}
```

I timed Import-Csv and each chunk export.  Import-/Export-Csv don't scale very well, but should be OK for the size/rows you're working with.  my final test CSV was 1.68 GB and ~1.1 million rows, 7200rpm drive on a 5-yo laptop - this should run much faster on better hardware:

```
Import-Csv : 00:05:51.2411580
Chunk 1    : 00:02:12.3754368
Chunk 2    : 00:01:16.5562393
Chunk 3    : 00:01:13.3434148
Chunk 4    : 00:01:14.5231756
Chunk 5    : 00:01:14.6382049

Total time : 00:13:02.6859795
```

the extra time from chunk1 might be a disk-related anomaly - in all the previous tests, all chunk times were near-identical, and the combined time for exports was roughly the same as the import time.

Comment: #Plan A: Using Pipes keep memory use low.  
get-content -path C:\temp\mybigfile.txt -raw | Select -first 200000 | Out-file -FilePath C:\temp\1file.txt
get-content -path C:\temp\mybigfile.txt -raw | select -Skip 200000 -First 200000 | Out-file -FilePath C:\temp\2file.txt

#Plan B: Have heard of people loading in a foreach.

foreach ($data in  get-content-path C:\temp\mybigfile.txt) {

}